# How do I plot only weekdays using Python's matplotlib candlestick?

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I'm not managing to plot matplotlib.finance.candlestick without the weekends (blank spaces between every 5 candlesticks).  The [example from Matplotlib's website](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html?highlight=candlestick) doesn't exclude weekends either and [the way to exclude weekends on other plots](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html) doesn't seem to apply to CandleSticks.

Has anybody come across this before?

ps. as requested, here is the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.dates import  DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, HourLocator, \
 DayLocator, MONDAY
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo, candlestick,\
 plot_day_summary, candlestick2

# (Year, month, day) tuples suffice as args for quotes_historical_yahoo
date1 = ( 2004, 2, 1)
date2 = ( 2004, 4, 12 )


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays    = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # Eg, Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # Eg, 12

quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo('INTC', date1, date2)

fig = figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

#plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
setp( gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

show()
```

Comment: Could you please post an minimal example?

Comment: @Zhenya, here's an example: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html?highlight=candlestick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intraday candlestick charts using MatPlotLib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673988/intraday-candlestick-charts-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 4):

After your 'quotes' line:

```
weekday_quotes = [tuple([i]+list(quote[1:])) for i,quote in enumerate(quotes)]
```

then

```
candlestick(ax, weekday_quotes, width=0.6)
```

This will plot the data without the gaps between weekdays, now you have to change the xticks back to dates, preferably mondays.  Assuming your first quote was a monday:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax.set_xticks(range(0,len(weekday_quotes),5))
ax.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(quotes[index][0]).strftime('%b-%d') for index in ax.get_xticks()])
```

This is pretty gross but seems to get the job done - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While @JMJR's answer works, I find this to be more robust:

```
def plot(x):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title("VIX curve")
    def idx(val=[0]):
        val[0] = val[0] + 1
        return val[0]
    d = collections.defaultdict(idx)
    # give each date an index
    [d[t] for t in sorted(x.index.get_level_values('baropen_datetime').unique())]
    # use the index
    x['idx'] = [d[t] for t in x.index.get_level_values('baropen_datetime')]
    # plot using index
    x.groupby('code').apply(lambda y: plt.plot(y.idx.values,
                                               y.close.values,
                                               label=y.index.get_level_values('code')[0]))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```