# Matplotlib remove space of candlestick for missing data

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I create a program that generate the candlestick chart and I have a problem with it. my data type is stock so it only have a data in weekdays.

So after I plotted it, it has spaces between the candlesticks.

[image: result image]

How can I remove these?

Here is my plotter function code:

```
ohlc = []
date = []
while (loop < candleLength) :
    date.append(dateToFloat(stockData['date'][loop]))
    append = date[loop], stockData['open'][loop], stockData['high'][loop], stockData['low'][loop], stockData['close'][loop]
    ohlc.append(append)
    loop += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))

candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.66, colorup='#4dff4d', colordown='#ff471a')


for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.grid(True)
```

Comment: `DataFormatter` is designed to display a continuous date range, so it would be better to plot your x-axis without this.

Comment: You should include example data in your code so people can test their solutions

Answer (score 2):

You can set `xticks` sequential numbers (0, 1, 2, 3 ... up to the number of candles you want to plot) and then set `xticklabels` actual dates for better visualization. See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992263/plotting-candlestick-with-matplotlib-for-time-series-w-o-weekend-gaps/47229291#47229291) for detailed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: [How do I plot only weekdays using Python's matplotlib candlestick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529492/how-do-i-plot-only-weekdays-using-pythons-matplotlib-candlestick)

This should answer your question. I use it as well in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your code.

```
def mydate(x,pos):
    try:
        return mdates[int(x)].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except IndexError:
        return ''

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))
```

Like this:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ohlc = []
date = []
while (loop < candleLength) :
    date.append(dateToFloat(stockData['date'][loop]))
    append = date[loop], stockData['open'][loop], stockData['high'][loop], stockData['low'][loop], stockData['close'][loop]
    ohlc.append(append)
    loop += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))

candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.66, colorup='#4dff4d', colordown='#ff471a')


for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)


def mydate(x,pos):
    try:
        return mdates[int(x)].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except IndexError:
        return ''

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.grid(True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please add some more explanation to your answer.