# How to plot candlestick skipping empty dates using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I'm still a newbie to matplotlib. Currently, I have below dataset for plotting:

> `Date   Open   High    Low  Close
>   Trade_Date
>   2018-01-02  736696.0  42.45  42.45  41.45  41.45
>   2018-01-03  736697.0  41.60  41.70  40.70  40.95
>   2018-01-04  736698.0  40.90  41.05  40.20  40.25
>   2018-01-05  736699.0  40.35  41.60  40.35  41.50
>   2018-01-08  736702.0  40.20  40.20  37.95  38.00
>   2018-01-09  736703.0  37.15  39.00  37.15  38.00
>   2018-01-10  736704.0  38.70  38.70  37.15  37.25
>   2018-01-11  736705.0  37.50  37.50  36.55  36.70
>   2018-01-12  736706.0  37.00  37.40  36.90  37.20
>   2018-01-15  736709.0  37.50  37.70  37.15  37.70
>   2018-01-16  736710.0  37.80  38.25  37.45  37.95
>   2018-01-17  736711.0  38.00  38.05  37.65  37.75
>   2018-01-18  736712.0  38.00  38.20  37.70  37.75
>   2018-01-19  736713.0  36.70  37.10  35.30  36.45
>   2018-01-22  736716.0  36.25  36.25  35.50  36.10
>   2018-01-23  736717.0  36.20  36.30  35.65  36.00
>   2018-01-24  736718.0  35.80  36.00  35.60  36.00
>   2018-01-25  736719.0  36.10  36.10  35.45  35.45
>   2018-01-26  736720.0  35.50  35.75  35.00  35.00
>   2018-01-29  736723.0  34.80  35.00  33.65  33.70
>   2018-01-30  736724.0  33.70  34.45  33.65  33.90`

I've converted the date value to number using `mdates.date2num`

After that, I've tried to plot candlestick graph with codes below:

```
    f1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (10,5))

   candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=.6, colorup='red', colordown='green')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    plt.show()
```

However, I'm still getting the graph with gaps.
I've tried the possible solution from [How do I plot only weekdays using Python's matplotlib candlestick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529492/how-do-i-plot-only-weekdays-using-pythons-matplotlib-candlestick)

However, I was not able to solve my problem with the solution above.

Can anyone kindly help me with this issue?

Thanks!