# matplotlib candlestick bars/boxes/width/spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am using matplotlib to draw candlestick charts.

[Q] The default setting shows the high-low bar running through the open-close box. I would prefer to have the open-low box be "above" the line so that I only see high-max(open,close) and min(open,close)-low as lines. Is that possible? How?

> I answered my own question and am posting my finding with the original question if it helps anyone else.
>
> The only way to do this is by rewriting the candletsick() function to draw two lines instead of one. I have some sample code that I am using that does this. Always happy to hear better ways to do the same thing.

```
def fooCandlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.5, colorup='k', colordown='r', 
                   alpha=1.0):
    OFFSET = width/2.0

    lines = []
    boxes = []
    for q in quotes:
        t, op, cl, hi, lo = q[:5]

        box_h = max(op, cl)
        box_l = min(op, cl)
        height = box_h - box_l

        if cl>=op:
            color = colorup
        else:
            color = colordown

        vline_lo = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(lo, box_l),
            color = 'k',
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
        )
        vline_hi = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(box_h, hi),
            color = 'k',
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
        )
        rect = Rectangle(
            xy = (t-OFFSET, box_l),
            width = width,
            height = height,
            facecolor = color,
            edgecolor = color,
        )
        rect.set_alpha(alpha)
        lines.append(vline_lo)
        lines.append(vline_hi)
        boxes.append(rect)
        ax.add_line(vline_lo)
        ax.add_line(vline_hi)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    return lines, boxes
```

[Q] Does matplotlib support setting the width of the candle and also the spacing between each candlestick?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have found a solution, the best thing to do is [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about spacing, but:

- You can set the transparency of the boxes using the `alpha` kwarg to `candlestick`. `1` should be opaque.
- You can set the width using the `width` kwarg, not sure what the units are, just play with them.

For example:

```
candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.5, alpha=1.0)
```

---

Ah, this answer adds empty data in between as a hack to increase the inter-candlestick spacing:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713447/1730674