# matplotlib.finance 5 minute intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, yahoo-finance

I have been using `matplotlib.finance` to pull stock information. `quotes_historical_yahoo()` is a really easy function to use but seems to only allow me to pull information on the day.

Is there a way using matplotlib to pull stock values in intervals of 5 minutes?

If not can I get a suggestion of some other python software that will do what I want.

Comment: I don't think there are any publicly available financial data sources that have historical stock prices in 5-minute intervals. For that data, you may need to use a paid service like Bloomberg. You could try to capture current and future 5-minute data yourself, but you'll probably get rate-limited by Yahoo/Google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673988/intraday-candlestick-charts-using-matplotlib

Further, http://www.quantshare.com/sa-426-6-ways-to-download-free-intraday-and-tick-data-for-the-us-stock-market

Lastly, I'd check out quantopian.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sources of historical data at varying resolutions [here](http://www.quantshare.com/sa-426-6-ways-to-download-free-intraday-and-tick-data-for-the-us-stock-market), but they dont go back very far. For example, you can only get ten days worth of data at the 1 minute interval from google finance.

I use pandas for historical data using DataReader(), and then read_csv() for the above sources (but that can get tricky and you will need to write your own code to format and make some of these useful)